# Expected mock function to have been called with. But it was not called. Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, jestjs

I have the following function that I want to test with `jest`.

```
import * as pointsAwardingApi from '../api/pointsAwardingApi';
export function awardPoints(pointsAwarding) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pointsAwardingApi.awardPoints(pointsAwarding);
    });
  };
}
```

Then, I created the following test.

```
import * as pointsAwardingApi from '../../../src/api/pointsAwardingApi';
it("should call award points api", () => {
  //given
  pointsAwardingApi.awardPoints = jest.fn();
  let dispatcher = pointsAwardingActions.awardPoints({phone: '555'});

  //when
  dispatcher(mockedDispatch);

  //then
  expect(pointsAwardingApi.awardPoints).toBeCalledWith({phone: '555'});
});
```

However, when I run the test I get the following error.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)
Expected mock function to have been called with: [{"phone": "555"}]
But it was not called.
```

I guess this is a problem with the `Promise` but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was missing adding a `spy` on the object.

```
jest.spyOn(pointsAwardingApi, 'awardPoints');
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how `spyOn` works atm. Which object did you add this on?

Comment: You just pass as argument the object and function you want to `spy`. Then you can call `expect` passing that function and check if it was called using `toBeCalledWith`. Take a look at the question above.